Phrase-usage tag?
Looking through the tags of this site, I don't see a tag named [phrase-usage] although it should be included with other tags like [phrase].
Additional question, can we change [phrase] to [phrases]? It makes sense to pluralise the tag.

It seems possible to use both phrase and usage tags here.  If we also have a tag phrase-usage, then people will tag questions using some combination of these three tags.  I don't recommend creating this tag (it's the kind of thing I'd edit away; or would be automatically edited away by the process that deleted once-off tags).
With regards to plural vs. singular tags, we're not particularly consistent:

translation (used) vs. translations;
usage (used) vs. usages;
word (used) vs. words;
difference (used) vs. differences;
pronunciation (used) vs. pronunciations;
verb vs. verbs (used);
character vs. characters (used);
expression vs. expressions (used);
tone vs. tones (used);
particle vs. particles (used).

Actually implementing a change like changing phrase to phrases would take a mod a matter of seconds.  The difficult part is coming to a consensus as to which tags to change.
Is changing phrase to phrases a change for the better?  I'm not sure.  Usually a post focuses on a single phrase; otherwise there's a risk it could be closed as:

Needs more focus This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

(Actually, in the future, could you please avoid "two questions in one" meta posts like this?  It makes it hard for people to vote, and hard to reference down the line.)
If we're going to tidy up singular vs. plural tags, maybe we should just do them all in one batch.
Hmm... meta posts at English.SE meta, ELL.SE meta, and WorldBuilding.SE meta preferred plurals.
